# How to store session in sublime working through ssh?

Tags: session, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sftp, sublime-text-plugin

Tools: I am editing my files using Sublime 2 and a great plugin SFTP.

Problem: I have several projects - for each of them I can at once modify 5-10 files. So to switch to other project each time I have to "Browse server" for the files I need and open them one by one. This is too long.

Question: How can I store the separate sessions so I would not have to open one by one file for each server I use?

Previous observation: I was trying to save the "Project" but probably it saves only the local files to it and after some time the saved this way session stops working.